# Compare the last string and previous string

Tags: php

I'm collecting a value (number) from grep command when page load:

```
$statsSum=shell_exec("grep --snipped--);
```

Result:

> $statsSum=100

I need this variable to be put on csv file, my attempt:

```
$fp = fopen('stats.csv', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $statsSum);
fclose($fp);
```

As a result, I have a number saved in a file. Now I need on NEXT reload of PHP page to get this number and compare it against the new value (number).

For example: first time page load: number written to file is 100.
Nex time page load, number is: 120, but maybe is not necessary to write it on on a file ? only to use it for compare ? or can be stored in a file also :)
I need to display the deference between two in percentage.

Results:

> 1-st laod: 100
>
> 2-nd load: 120
>
> Current statistics is: 120 (20% more then previous)

Thank you !!!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You did not ask an actual question here, you just told us what you “need”. This is not a code-writing service, you need to show what you tried, and explain what exactly the specific problem was that you did not manage to solve on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in a session that will be saved across page loads:

```
session_start();
$previous = $_SESSION['statsSum'] ?? 0;
$_SESSION['statsSum'] = shell_exec("grep --snipped--");

if($_SESSION['statsSum'] > $previous) {
    $difference = $_SESSION['statsSum'] - $previous;
    echo "Current statistics is: {$_SESSION['statsSum']} {$difference}% more than previous)";
} elseif($_SESSION['statsSum'] < $previous) {
    $difference = $previous - $_SESSION['statsSum'];
    echo "Current statistics is: {$_SESSION['statsSum']} {$difference}% less than previous)";
} else {
    echo "Current statistics is: {$_SESSION['statsSum']} the same as previous)";
}
```

Or whatever logic you want for `>`, `<` or `=`.